# send message Server to Client in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to send message to client from Spring MVC framework **Service class** like under code

```
@Override
    public void updateBoard(Map<String, Object> map) throws Exception {
        String password = boardDAO.selectPassword(map);

        if (!password.isEmpty() && !password.equals(map.get("PASSWORD"))) {
            return;
        }else {
            //TODO need to send message to client when password is wrong
        }

        updatelogDAO.insertUpdateLog(map);
        boardDAO.updateBoard(map);
    }
```

how to send message Server **'Service'** to Client in **Spring MVC**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `ModelAndView` like this:

```
 return new ModelAndView("password", "messageError", password);
```

Or use `Model` like this:

```
  public void updateBoard(Map<String, Object> map, Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("passwordError", message);
   ....
```